# set custom font on Label with libgdx crash

Tags: android-studio, fonts, libgdx, load

i have the problem with load the ttf file, my code:

```
Label migliaLabel;
migliaLabel = new Label("label", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Kalam-Regular.ttf")), Color.MAGENTA));
```

the file Kalam-Regular.ttf is in the folder assets/Kalam-Regular.ttf
but when i run the game, android studio get in error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 125
>                                                                                  com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error loading font file:
>   Kalam-Regular.ttf
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:665)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.(BitmapFont.java:475)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.(BitmapFont.java:114)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.(BitmapFont.java:107)
>                                                                                      at com.surfsurvivor.game.GameClass.show(GameClass.java:181)
>                                                                                      at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
>                                                                                      at com.surfsurvivor.game.SurfClass.create(SurfClass.java:26)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:254)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505)
>                                                                                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
>                                                                                   Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Invalid
>   padding.
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.load(BitmapFont.java:488)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont$BitmapFontData.(BitmapFont.java:475) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.(BitmapFont.java:114) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.(BitmapFont.java:107) 
>                                                                                      at com.surfsurvivor.game.GameClass.show(GameClass.java:181) 
>                                                                                      at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61) 
>                                                                                      at com.surfsurvivor.game.SurfClass.create(SurfClass.java:26) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:254) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1505) 
>                                                                                      at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with TTF files, LibGDX has a library called [FreeType](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) that lets you generate `BitmapFont` objects from TTF files. An example of how to generate a font from a TTF file might look like this:

```
    /**Initialises the generator using the file location given.*/
    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.local(fontLocation));
    params = new FreeTypeFontParameter();

    /**Sets the parameters of the object constant for the font, regardless of size.*/
    params.borderWidth = BORDER_WIDTH;
    params.borderColor = Color.BLACK;
    params.characters = FreeTypeFontGenerator.DEFAULT_CHARS;
    params.magFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
    params.minFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
    params.genMipMaps = true;
    params.size = FONT_SIZE;

    /**Generates the font using the generator object.*/
    font = generator.generateFont(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved using Hiero , you can download from the site [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html) and converts the file ttf files .fnt . Now it works for me .

now set the font:

```
migliaLabel = new Label("label", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("Kalam-Regular.fnt")), Color.MAGENTA));
```